# A general moment made up from a pair of independent Gaussian random variables $A$ and $B$ with identical variance factorizes?

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $A$ and $B$ be real-valued, centered and independent Gaussian random variables such that
\begin{equation}
Cov(A,A)=Cov(B,B):=C 
\end{equation}
Since they are independent, it is clear that
\begin{equation}
Cov(A,B)=Cov(B,A)=0.
\end{equation}

Now, for a fixed even $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ be any given random variables such that
\begin{equation}
\text{each } X_i \text{ is either } A \text{ or } B
\end{equation}
for all $i=1, \cdots, n$.

Then, I wonder if I can express the their moment
\begin{equation}
E[X_1 \cdots X_n]
\end{equation}
as
\begin{equation}
\prod_{i=1}^n C_i
\end{equation}
where $C_i = C_1, \cdots, C_n$ are some prescribed values. Moreover, are these $C_i$'s expressible in terms of the variance $C$ above?

Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution provides a way to compute the higher moments in general cases. However, I cannot figure out myself if the moments factorize when the covariance matrix is proportional to the identity.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: If $X_i, A,B$ are vectors, how do you define $X_1X_2 $ or $AB$ or $A^2$?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I assume that $A, B$ are real-valued. I will clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expectation satisfies
$$E[X_1\cdots X_n]=E[A^k\cdot B^{n-k}]=E[A^k]\cdot E[B^{n-k}]$$
where k is the number of $X_i$ that are equal to $A$.

Since $A$ and $B$ are centered, their moments are equal to their central moments. The central moments of a Gaussian random variable can be expressed in terms of the standard deviation by the following formulae,
\begin{align}
E[(X-E[X])^{n}]&=\sigma^{n}(n-1)!!&\text{for n even}\\\\
E[(X-E[X])^{n}]&=0&\text{for n odd}
\end{align}
This gives us that
$$E[A^k]\cdot E[B^{n-k}]=\bigr((k-1)!!\cdot C^{k/2}\bigl)\cdot \bigr((n-k-1)!!C^{(n-k)/2}\bigl)=(k-1)!!\cdot (n-k-1)!! \cdot C^{n/2}$$
if $k$ and $n-k$ are both even, and
$$E[A^k]\cdot E[B^{n-k}]=0$$
if either $k$ or $n-k$ are odd.

Since $n$ is even, the requirement reduces to simply that $k$ be even, and we have
\begin{align}
E[X_1\cdots X_n]&=E[A^k]\cdot E[B^{n-k}]=(k-1)!!\cdot (n-k-1)!!\cdot C^{n/2} &\text{for k even}\\
E[X_1\cdots X_n]&=E[A^k]\cdot E[B^{n-k}]=0&\text{for k odd}
\end{align}